# Soundcloud Accept: application/json

Tags: json, soundcloud

I am trying to get an answer from soundcloud API using the "Accept" header instead of add .json to the resource URI but it doesn't work:

```
curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207?client_id=CLIENT_ID" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

It returns an answer in xml format.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is it a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Your request responds with JSON for me.

Comment: Yes, now it's working for me too.... It's a little weird, when I tried it last week returned in xml format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `&format=json` param to the url